# In React Router, is it possible to do a sync action before the user is being redirected?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

How is it possible inside a Link, to get the url from the server before redirecting to user to it?

This is what I've tried:

```
render() {
    return (
        <AppContext.Consumer>
            {context => (
                <div className="container">
                       // get url from server, and then navigate
                    <Link onClick=??? to={context.generatedUrl}>
                        <button>
                            Navigate !
                        </button>
                    </Link>
                </div>
            )}
        </AppContext.Consumer>
    )
}
```

The problem of course is that the onClick function is async, so the response comes after the user has been redirected. How can I **get the url** from the server, **and then** **navigate** to the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's not possible using Links, you will have to do the routing programmatically

```
    const Component = ({history}) => {
      const handleClick = () => {
        const url = await yourFunction();
        history.push(url)
      }
      return (
        <button onClick={handleClick}>Navigate !</button>
      );
    }
```

Using classes

```
    class MyComponent extends Component {
      async function handleClick() {
        const url = await yourFunction();
        this.props.history.push(url)
      }
      render() {
        return <button onClick={handleClick}>Navigate !</button>
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks ! could you please show me how to use this inside a class instead?

Comment: Well, it says "can use const only in typescript files", and if i remove it, await only usable outside async functions.

Comment: sorry, I have a long time without using classes, I edited it again